# Nice proof that de Rham complex computes Lie algebra cohomology?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks, derham-cohomology, koszul-duality

If $G$ is a nice enough group acting on a nice enough space $X$, then the relative de Rham complex
$$\Omega^\bullet_{X/(X/G)}\ \simeq\ \mathcal{O}_X\otimes\text{Sym}\,\mathfrak{g}^*[-1]$$
is given by (a sheafy version of) the [Chevalley-Eilenberg complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_cohomology#Chevalley%E2%80%93Eilenberg_complex) of $\mathcal{O}_X$, computing Lie algebra cohomology $\mathcal{H}^*(\mathfrak{g},\mathcal{O}_X)$.

Is there a zero-computation proof of this, e.g. using that $\Omega^\bullet$ is Koszul dual to differential operators $\mathcal{D}$, and that $\mathfrak{g}$ is Koszul dual to the Chevalley-Eilenberg complex $\text{Sym}\,\mathfrak{g}^*[-1]$?

Comment: I have no rigorous argument, but one way to "see" this is that $X$ is isomorphic to the pullback $X/G\times_{BG}\ast$, where the map $X/G\to BG$ classifies the $G$-bundle $X\to X/G$ (or equivalently, it is the homotopy $G$-orbits of the $G$-equivariant map $X\to\ast$). By base change property of de Rham complex, you are reduced to the computation of $\Omega_{\ast/BG}$.